# Integrate current models from models.Model to BaseModel django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations

I've some models from models.Model in django and wish to know if I change it and extend to BaseModel will occur some error when I make migrations. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If your `BaseModel` extends `models.Model`.

Answer (score 1):

If `BaseModel` is abstract, then changing a model to inherit from `models.Model` to `BaseModel` will not require a migration.

If `BaseModel` is not abstract, then you are switching to multi-table inheritance, and migrations will be required.

See the Django docs on [inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance) for more info.